# WPF c# DateTimePicker or DateTimeUpDown changing date using arrow keys or mouse wheel

Tags: c#, wpf, datetimepicker

The problem is that I can't change Time or Date at all in both controls by using mouse wheel, arrow up/down keys or even that small up/down arrows in the right of textbox. Both controls are from Extended WPF Toolkit (https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/)

The only working solution is to use DateTimePicker, press calendar button, and there everything starts working, but not on the textbox itself. I've just tried it in totally empty project and the problem persisted.

**What I am missing? How to make both of these controls work as it would be WinForms DateTimePicker?**

This is my xaml:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" x:Class="WPFForm.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <xctk:DateTimePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="162,167,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="271"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Also, there isn't any difference whether I'm binding the Value property or not.

Comment: What is the version of you are using? I see in the comments [here](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker) there were some issues with previous versions already solved

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've downloaded it two days ago, so I'm using the newest: Extended WPF Toolkit - 2.0.0, May 21, 2013, Stable.

I will try to use older version and will post here if it helps.

Comment: Juan, you were right. I've downloaded 1.9.0.0 version and it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Juan is right. The problem exists within 2.0.0, 1.8.0.0 and maybe in others version. So, the solution is to use 1.9.0.0 version and it works fine!